# UV map is not alligning with the mesh

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking

i made this simple character and UV unwrapped it. With the procedual shader it looks fine but when i bake the diffuse and then plug the baked image back into the base color it has black marks on it. I tried to make the UVs better by manually placing seams but it did not work.
Thanks

With Procedual Texture:
[image]

With Baked Diffuse Texture:
[image]

Blender File:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like a bug to me. I corrected it by exporting the object as .obj and re-importing it in a fresh scene, which seems to clean it up.

Now, this is the teacher in me speaking, and is unrelated, but I would improve the uvs, as they show massive stretching.

Comment: Ok Thank you that worked!